# Unable to edit array data in For Each Loop

Tags: vb.net

Like title, running this code shows an array with all 0 values in it.

I have tried using integer array too but I can't

```vb
Dim woohoo(9) As String
Dim count As Integer = 2
For Each number As String In woohoo
    number = CStr(count)
    count += 2
Next

For Each number As Integer In woohoo
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```

> 2,4,6,8,10...20

Comment: Why have you got two loops over the same array with one treating the elements as `Strings` and one treating them as `Integers`?  Make up your mind whether you want to work with `Strings` or `Integers` and do it.

Comment: As for the issue, where do you actually put anything into the array?  Nowhere.  I see you setting the `number` variable but that's not the array.  If you want something in the array, put something in the array.  You're not going to do that with a `For Each` loop, which is only for using items already in a list.

Comment: Thanks, I just knew I never used ```For Each``` loop for inserting data before. Now I understand, I'll refer to other For Loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this to SET the values of an array:

```
Dim wooho(9) As Integer
Dim count As Integer = 2

For i As Integer = 0 To wooho.Count - 1
   wooho(i) = count
   count += 2
   Console.WriteLine(wooho(i))
Next
```

And this to GET the values:

```
For Each number As Integer In wooho
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a list of Integers for this.
Try this:

```
    Dim woohoo As New List (Of Integer)
    Dim count As Integer = 2 
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        woohoo.Items.Add (count)
        count += 2
    Next

    For Each number As Integer In woohoo
        Console.WriteLine(CStr(number))
    Next
```

Comment: If the size is not changing, there's no point to using a `List` rather than an array.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I used a list instead of an array because of easier iterations and less code.

Comment: Neither of those is a thing.  You could just change `woohoo.Items.Add (count)` to `woohoo(i) = count`.  How is that harder or more code?